# Counting the occurrence of one dataframe column as a substring in another using PySpark Dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark

I have a pyspark dataframe (df1) with a column that looks like the following:

```
+---------------+
|     fruit     |
+---------------+
| apple, orange |
| apple, banana |
| banana, grape |
+---------------+
```

and another dataframe (df2) with a column that looks like the following:

```
+-----------------------+
|         items         |
+-----------------------+
| apple, orange, banana |
| apple, orange, grape  |
| apple, banana, grape  |
+-----------------------+
```

I need to count the occurrence of each row in df1 in df2
so the resulting dataframe should look like this:

```
+---------------+------------+
|     fruit     |  frequency |
+---------------+------------+
| apple, orange |      2     |
| apple, banana |      2     |
| banana, grape |      1     |
+---------------+------------+
```

Hope this makes sense, appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to do it is doing a join, but first you need a litter bit of preprocessing:

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

fruits = spark.createDataFrame(
  [["apple, orange"],
   ["apple, banana"],
   ["banana, grape"]],
  schema=["fruits"]                      
)

items = spark.createDataFrame(
  [["apple, orange, banana"],
   ["apple, orange, grape"],
   ["apple, banana, grape"]],
  schema=["items"]                      
)
```

First of all, use [`regexp_replace`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.regexp_replace.html) to get rid of unwanted spaces. After that, use [`split`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.split.html?highlight=split#pyspark.sql.functions.split) to get an array of elements instead of a simple string:

```py
fruits = fruits.withColumn("fruit_list", F.regexp_replace("fruits", " ", "")) \
               .withColumn("fruit_list", F.split("fruit_list", ","))

items = items.withColumn("item_list", F.regexp_replace("items", " ", "")) \
             .withColumn("item_list", F.split("item_list", ","))

items.show(truncate=False)
```

```
+---------------------+-----------------------+
|items                |item_list              |
+---------------------+-----------------------+
|apple, orange, banana|[apple, orange, banana]|
|apple, orange, grape |[apple, orange, grape] |
|apple, banana, grape |[apple, banana, grape] |
+---------------------+-----------------------+
```

Now join rows that fulfill the given condition. For that we use [`array_except`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.array_except.html?highlight=array_except#pyspark.sql.functions.array_except) and [`size`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.size.html?highlight=size#pyspark.sql.functions.size). If after subtracting `item_list` to `fruit_list` the size is zero, then we know all elements of `fruit_list` are on `items_list`:

```py
join_expr = F.size(F.array_except(fruits.fruit_list, items.item_list)) == 0

fruits.join(items, join_expr) \
  .groupBy("fruits").count() \
  .show()
```

```
+-------------+-----+
|       fruits|count|
+-------------+-----+
|apple, orange|    2|
|apple, banana|    2|
|banana, grape|    1|
+-------------+-----+
```

Groupby and count to get the result you want!

Answer (score 1):

Cross join the two dataframes then split the columns and calculate the set difference using `array_except`. Then create a boolean `flag` to identify the rows where the set difference is zero i.e. complete overlap. Finally, group the dataframe and aggregate the `flag` with sum.

```
df3 = df1.join(df2, how='cross')

flag = F.size(F.array_except(F.split('fruit', ', '), F.split('items', ', '))) == 0
df3 = df3.groupBy('fruit').agg(F.sum(flag.cast('int')).alias('frequency'))
```

---

```
df3.show()
+-------------+---------+
|        fruit|frequency|
+-------------+---------+
|apple, orange|        2|
|apple, banana|        2|
|banana, grape|        1|
+-------------+---------+
```